# launch Apple Maps in iPhone by passing the parameters for showing in callout pop

Tags: ios, custom-attributes, launch, apple-maps

I am working on opening the Apples default app from my app by using the code

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication ]openUrl:""];
```

I need to pass custom latitude/longitude or the location name also the details(address ,Phone) of pin to be shown in callout popup.

Is there any way i can create a query string like format and append in my parameters ?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Sagar

Comment: If you are supporting iOS 6 and later you should use the `MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:` method to launch the Apple Maps app.

Comment: If you really want to use `openURL:` then see the [Map Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1) document.